# Midpoint of a segment

Tags: triangles

Let ABC be a triangle, I and J are two points such that : $\overrightarrow{AI}=\frac {2}{3}\overrightarrow {AB}$ and $\overrightarrow{AC}=\frac {1}{2}\overrightarrow {AJ}$.

(BC) and (IJ) intersect in O.

Show that O is the midpoint of  the segment [BC].

Comment: Hello, welcome to MSE. Can you please include your own attempts in the question? Questions that do not show that you made an effort on your own are generally poorly received here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

We have that

- line $IJ:\quad P(t)=AI+t(AJ-AI)$
- line $BC:\quad Q(s)=AB+s(AC-AB)$

then equate $P(t)=Q(s)$ and use that ${AI}=\frac {2}{3} {AB}$ and ${AC}=\frac {1}{2} {AJ}$ to find the intersection point $O$. Finally check that $O$ is the midpoint of $BC$.

[image]

Comment: Thank you sir for your help